# How to loop through wildcard search function

Tags: vba, loops

I created a script that would search through a given directory with a wildcard and output any folder it matches. The problem I am running into: there are multiple folders with the wildcard it matches... my script only returns the very first folder it matches and stops.

Is there i can have the code loop through the directory (in my case D:\P) and output all matching folders?

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
Dim sFile As String, sPathSeek As String, sPathMatch As String

   Dim sMainPath As String
   sMainPath = sfolderPath 'D:\P\

   Dim Path1 As String 'THIS IS THE FIRST STRING I NEED A WILDCARD TO FIND
   Path1 = "_Links"
   Dim Path2 As String 'THIS IS THE SECOND STRING I NEED A WILDCARD TO FIND
   Path2 = "TLP"


'FIND THE FOLDER THAT CONTAINS THE FIRST PATH USING A WILDCARD
    On Error Resume Next
    sPathSeek = sMainPath & "*" & Path1
    sFile = Dir(sPathSeek, vbDirectory)


    Do While Len(sFile) > 0
        If Left(sFile, 1) <> "." Then
            If (GetAttr(sFile) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                sPathMatch = sFile
                Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        sFile = Dir
    Loop


    MsgBox IIf(sPathMatch = "", "Match not found", "Match: " & sPathMatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Sep as string
'....
Sep = ""
Do While Len(sFile) > 0
    If Left(sFile, 1) <> "." Then
        If (GetAttr(sFile) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            sPathMatch = sPathMatch & Sep & sFile
            Sep = ", "
        End If
    End If
    sFile = Dir
Loop


MsgBox IIf(sPathMatch = "", "Match not found", "Match: " & sPathMatch)
```

Edit: here's one example of how to collect all the "TLP" folders which reside directly under "_Links"

```
Sub TestFolderMatches()

    Dim col As Collection, f

    Set col = GetFolderMatches("C:\_Stuff\test")
    For Each f In col
        Debug.Print f
    Next f

End Sub



'Return a collection of folders matching "*\_Links\TLP" given a starting folder
Function GetFolderMatches(startFolder As String) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr
    Dim colFolders As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder

    Do While colSub.Count > 0

        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1

        For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
            'collect any folder named "TLP" inside a "_Links" folder
            If subFldr.Name = "TLP" And fldr.Name = "_Links" Then
                colFolders.Add subFldr.Path '<< collect this one
            Else
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path '<< search this one
            End If

        Next subFldr
    Loop

    Set GetFolderMatches = colFolders '<< return the collected folders

End Function
```

Comment: This does not seem to have made a difference in the code, i am still getting the same output as it does not loop through the entire set of folders. Is there a way for the code to read all folders in D:\P\ and return any matching folders using a wildcard?

Comment: Are you talking about direct subfolders of the path being scanned, or nested subfolders some levels deeper ?

Comment: I am trying to get all folders within D:\P\ containing a string (in this case the wildcard is "_Links" or "TLP"). I am using this code on multiple computers and would like to know which "_Links" or "TLP" folders exist on these computers. My code only searches for one folder then it stops, i would need it to continue searching throughout D:\P\ and return the rest of the folders containing the wildcard.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear - do you need to keep searching through the entire folder tree below `D:\P\` or are you only looking for folders directly under that path (ie. not looking for folders within folders within folders...) ? Your current approach will only search at one level.

Comment: Yes i would need to keep searching through the entire folder tree. In my case i would be looking into D:\P\ find any "*_Links" folders and go within that folder and find any "TLP*" folders.

Comment: any help Tim? Thanks

Comment: Are all the "TLP" folders directly under "_Links" folders?  Are there _Links folders nested within other _Links folders ?

Comment: yes, all TLP folders are directly under _Links folders. There are no _Links folders nested within other _Links folders.